# Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'digital_chuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando conectarme a la base de datos con pdo en HostGator pero recibo el siguiente error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'digital_chuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Mi código de conexion es:

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','TK$JhM,XV&tD>');
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Al final tengo este otro mensaje:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   /home3/digital/public_html/chevistar/index.php on line 6

He creado la base de datos y usuario en el apartado de MySQL Databases y he agregado dicho usuario a la base, cuando voy a PHPMYADMIN veo la base creada con sus tablas, sin embargo cuando reviso MYSQL Databases aparece como una base de datos vacía no se is por ahí está la pista.

Comment: Muestra el código de tu sentencia donde ocupas prepare

Comment: $sel = $con->prepare("SELECT id,concesionario FROM concesionarios");
 $sel-> execute();
 $traerDatos = $sel->fetchAll();

Comment: en ciertas ocasiones `localhost` no es igual a `127.0.0.1` donde está el mysql. (blame HostGator)

Answer (score 1):

Hola como están realmente les agradezco mucho por sus respuestas he encontrado el problema y lo he resuelto, efectivamente es un tema que pasa por la conexión a la base de datos, específicamente en la definición del host. Hay dos soluciones a este inconveniente espero que les sirva si se encuentran con este tipo de error:

1.- La primera solución y la más fácil es definir el host=localhost por su ip equivalente es decir:

```
<?php
try {
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Se reemplaza localhost por 127.0.0.1 que es la ip que hace referencia al host en el que está alojado el sitio.

La segunda solución es reemplazar localhost por el server ip, lo complicado con esta forma es que esta dirección no está visible por lo general en el c-panel o en ninguna parte del host contratado por lo que será necesario contactarse con la directamente con personal del host para que te brinden esta información.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos que le pases a tu conexión; pueden ser de dos modos: tanto local como remota, explico

1.- Local (haciendo referencia a tu propio equipo de cómputo)

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','TK$JhM,XV&tD>');
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

> Donde como puedes notar en `mysql:host=localhost` así le indico que
>   apunte a una instalación dentro de la propia computadora

2.- Remota: Haciendo referencia por ejemplo a la IP del servidor donde se encuentra alojado el gestor de bases de datos que va a contener tu base de datos

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.12;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','TK$JhM,XV&tD>');
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

> Donde como puedes notar en `mysql:host=192.168.0.12` así le indico que
>   se conecte a una dirección IP remota que corresponde a la del servidor
>   que tengas rentado

Para el error específico

Te esta indicando que tienes un error por haber escrito una contraseña, lo que deberías hacer es dejar ese espacio sin ningún valor asignado

**EJEMPLO**

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','');
```

> Como puedes notar el espacio de la contraseña, lo dejo sin ningún
>   valor y sin espacio en medio de las comillas simples para que así se
>   interprete que no existe valor asignado

Comment: Hola Alfredo estoy intentando cargar todo en mi host no es un servidor externo, o no se si te entendí bien.

Comment: Entonces quita la contraseña

Comment: Gracias Alfredo por tu interés en verdad te entendí mal, si debo cambiar Localhost y contraseña. Lo que no estoy seguro es donde encontrar esa información: ip del servidor y la contraseña del c-panel.

Comment: SI TE Sitvio que te dije?

Comment: Que tal Alfredo, estoy aún buscando la ip del servidor y la contraseña, no se donde encontrar esa información. Puedes guiarme ?

Answer (score 0):

El segundo error es consecuencia del primero así que concentrémonos en ese. El primero, indica que la conexión a la base de datos en localhost no se pudo realizar con el usuario y claves indicados.

Esto suele ocurrir cuando las credenciales ingresadas son erróneas, es decir, nombre de usuario o contraseña equivocados.

Viendo que en el código que compartes utilizas otro usuario diferente (digital_chevuser) al que se indica en el mensaje de error (digital_chuser) te recomendaría que revisaras cuál es el correcto y pruebes la conexión nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias! me funciono!con este:
EJEMPLO

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=digital_chdb','digital_chevuser','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola para los que se les complica yo lo pude resolver de una forma facil y es que el problema esta en la contraseña al tener contraseña con simbolos no la acepta bien les recomiendo que usen una contraseña sin mayuscula y sin simbolos, despues importan los datos de nuevos y queda esa es la solucion